# Python library for manipulating very large matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, large-data

What's a good Python library for manipulating very large matrices (e.g. millions of rows/columns), including the ability to add rows or columns at any stage of the matrix's life?

I had looked at [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) and [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/), but neither support adding or removing rows or columns once the matrix is created.

The only other thing I could find was the sparse matrix functionality in numpy/scipy noted in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368544/how-can-i-remove-a-column-from-a-sparse-matrix-efficiently) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695337/expanding-adding-a-row-or-column-a-scipy-sparse-matrix). However, the ability to add/remove rows and columns seems possible but officially unsupported and a bit hacky, so I'm fearing the performance would be horrible with a real dataset. Also, it includes several different sparse matrix implementations, so I'm confused which one would be best (e.g. lil_matrix vs csc_matrix vs csr_matrix).

Answer (score 2):

If your matrix is sparse you can add or remove rows or columns without hackying with `scipy.sparse`. If you want to remove columns (do column slicing) you should go for `csc_matrix`, while the `csr_matrix` should be used for efficient row slicing. Usually it is convenient to create the sparse matrix using the `coo_matrix` type, where you can specify the `row`, `col` and `data` for each non-zero entry:

```
m = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(nrow, ncol))
m = m.to_csr()[rows_to_keep, :]
m = m.to_csc()[:, cols_to_keep]
```

where `rows_to_keep` can be a list or a 1-D array with the indices to keep.

If you need a dense matrix you can use perhaps the `numpy.memmap()` array. To create one you can do:

```
a = np.memmap('test.memmap', dtype='float64', mode='w+', shape=(1000, 1000))
a.fill(100.)
```

To read one you can do:

```
a = np.memmap('a.memmap', dtype='float64', mode='r+', shape=(1000, 1000))
```

If you want to remove or add rows and columns you have to create a second memmap array and then assign the columns that you want from the original one:

```
b = np.memmap('b.memmap', dtype='float64', mode='w+', shape=(3, 1000))
b = a[[0, 99, 199], :]
```

this will save in `b` the first, 100th and 200th rows of `a`, with all the columns.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object does not support indexing`. It seems strange to me that any matrix type couldn't be indexed, since that's the whole purpose of a matrix... I'll assume that is explained in the scipy docs, but http://docs.scipy.org has been offline the last couple days.

Comment: @Cerin yes, you have to convert before using `to_csr()` or `to_csc()`, then the indexing should work...

Comment: @Cerin I believe the purpose of the `coo_matrix` is to provide one type of sparse matrix which is easy to populate ans fast to convert to the other types (`csr_matrix` or `csc_matrix` for example)