# Delete columns of matrix of CSR format in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix (22000x97482) in csr format and i want to delete some columns (indices of columns numbers are stored in a list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368544/how-can-i-remove-a-column-from-a-sparse-matrix-efficiently

Comment: Not really, it is another format of sparse matrix. i'd tried but no result

Comment: I think you need to do column based slices then (bound to be slow in CSR format). If you do this a lot, CSR is probably not a good choice choice, maybe use CSC instead, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352280/slicing-sparse-matrices-in-scipy-which-types-work-best

Comment: From the documentation: `Disadvantages of the CSR format
slow column slicing operations (consider CSC)`.  It's common practice in `sparse` to convert matricies to the optimal type before acting.

Comment: In some quick tests, `X[I,:]` is about 10x faster than `X[:,I]` for a `csr` matrix.  `X.tocsc[:,I]` is a bit faster than `X[:,I]`.  So if you are doing a lot of column slicing it is worth the extra step of converting to a `csc` format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use fancy indexing to obtain a new `csr_matrix` with the columns that you have in your list:

```
all_cols = np.arange(old_m.shape[1])
cols_to_keep = np.where(np.logical_not(np.in1d(all_cols, cols_to_delete)))[0]
m = old_m[:, cols_to_keep]
```

Comment: Explicitly generating all column indices is not really ideal if you have a huge number of columns

Comment: @ali_m thank you for the feedback. I couldn't come out with a better approach. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

If you have a very large number of columns then generating the full set of column indices can become rather costly. One slightly faster alternative would be to temporarily convert to [COO format](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def dropcols_fancy(M, idx_to_drop):
    idx_to_drop = np.unique(idx_to_drop)
    keep = ~np.in1d(np.arange(M.shape[1]), idx_to_drop, assume_unique=True)
    return M[:, np.where(keep)[0]]

def dropcols_coo(M, idx_to_drop):
    idx_to_drop = np.unique(idx_to_drop)
    C = M.tocoo()
    keep = ~np.in1d(C.col, idx_to_drop)
    C.data, C.row, C.col = C.data[keep], C.row[keep], C.col[keep]
    C.col -= idx_to_drop.searchsorted(C.col)    # decrement column indices
    C._shape = (C.shape[0], C.shape[1] - len(idx_to_drop))
    return C.tocsr()
```

Check equivalence:

```
m, n, d = 1000, 2000, 20

M = sparse.rand(m, n, format='csr')
idx_to_drop = np.random.randint(0, n, d)

M_drop1 = dropcols_fancy(M, idx_to_drop)
M_drop2 = dropcols_coo(M, idx_to_drop)

print(np.all(M_drop1.A == M_drop2.A))
# True
```

Benchmark:

```
In [1]: m, n = 1000, 1000000

In [2]: %%timeit M = sparse.rand(m, n, format='csr')
   ...: dropcols_fancy(M, idx_to_drop)
   ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.11 s per loop

In [3]: %%timeit M = sparse.rand(m, n, format='csr')
   ...: dropcols_coo(M, idx_to_drop)
   ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 365 ms per loop
```

Comment: You could use `searchsorted` instead of the `greater_outer` for a little more speed. Would probably be a good idea to call `unique(idx_to_drop)` as well :-)

Comment: @morningsun Thanks for fixing my mistake, and for your other suggestions. Using `searchsorted` to decrement the column indices is a major improvement over using broadcasting, especially when `idx_to_drop` is large. I wish I'd thought of it myself!